# Spring Boot Integration Test - Maven Tests missing JSTL

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test

I am trying to implement an integration test using Selenium for our application. The idea was to load the applicationcontext of our SpringMVC project, start an embedded Tomcat container and then run integration tests on it, before shutting down and finalizing the applications compilation.

Now running the JUnit test out of Eclipse starts up the server with Spring Boot perfectly, however when running Maven tests and accessing the website (through Selenium or not), I get the following exception:

`org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application`

However, JSTL is on the classpath for scope `test` in Maven.  Does anybody know, why this is happening?

My configuration is split up over a parent project, an internal library used in our projects and another one for the actual project. I omitted uninteresting parts of the pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <apache.tiles.version>3.0.4</apache.tiles.version>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.59</tomcat.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>${apache.tiles.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
    <version>${apache.tiles.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
    <version>${apache.tiles.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.47.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

TestConfig.java:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({ GVAppConfiguration.class, SecSecurityConfig.class, TestMvcConfig.class })
@ImportResource({ "classpath:applicationContext.xml", "classpath:/META-INF/applicationContext-commons.xml",
    "classpath:/applicationContext-solr.xml" })
public class TestConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(TestConfig.class);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestConfig.class);
    }
}
```

IndexControllerTest.java:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
@WebIntegrationTest(value = "server.port=9000")
@SeleniumTest(driver = FirefoxDriver.class, baseUrl = "http://localhost:9000")
public class IndexControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebDriver webDriver;

    @Test
    public void testController() {
    webDriver.getTitle();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that by default Maven's Surefire plugin employs a trick wherein it creates a Manifest-Only JAR file, in order to avoid the need to pass the full classpath to the forked JRE (see this article). The Jetty JSP processor simply asks each classloader for its list of URLs, and so only sees the one manifest-only JAR file, rather than all the JAR files that are actually being used, and hence doesn't find the TLD files.

The simple solution, which is also documented on that page, is to turn off the useManifestOnlyJar option, as follows:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ....
<plugin>
```

This instructs Surefire to directly pass the full classpath to the forked JRE process, thereby allowing it to locate the TLDs.
Answer taken [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835845/cant-find-jstl-tag-library-when-running-test-under-maven-surefire).

Answer (score 0):

Try deps like this :

```
<groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything, I'm afraid. JSTL is already on the classpath and is just being ignored during runtime, when spring-boot is fired up during a maven test. And only at runtime.